# Child rotating around parent axes instead of his own

Tags: c++, rotation, parent-child, ros, axes

So, I have a C ++ project which is simulating a car. 
My program is working in 2D(only in the XY plane), it feed with odometries data gave by a rosbag, giving him his position in the XYplane depending of the world origin. Everything is fine in 2D.

But when I am in 3D, meaning I can rotate my car around several axes, not only Z anymore.
I realized that my car is rotating around the axes of the "world" axes, when I would like them to turn around my vehicle axes.

In order to test it, I did a dummy code where my vehicle is suppose to do a 90deg rotation one the Z axe and then a 90 deg rotation on Y axe.

I can do to have my vehicle rotating around his own axes ? 
How would the math would be ?

In the following the two rotations are done around the world axes.

Here is a piece of my code to illustrate:

```
void NodeImpl::callback_odometry(motion_common_msg::Odometry input_msg)
{
  //Getting Direction3D

//---
    frame_id = input_msg.header.frame_id;
    stamp = input_msg.header.stamp;

    transform_from_odometry.setOrigin(new_position_3D);

    tf::Quaternion q;
    q.setRPY(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    transform_from_odometry.setRotation(q);

    if(input_msg.pos_x >= 5.0)
    {
        double cos90 = 0;
        double sin90 = 1;

        tf::Matrix3x3 Rz90;
        tf::Matrix3x3 Ry90;

        Rz90.setValue(cos90, - sin90, 0, sin90, cos90, 0, 0, 0, 1);
        Ry90.setValue(cos90, 0, sin90, 0, 1, 0, -sin90, 0, cos90);

        tf::Quaternion qz90;
        tf::Quaternion qy90;

        Rz90.getRotation(qz90);
        Ry90.getRotation(qy90);

        qz90.normalize();
        qy90.normalize();

        tf::Transform tf_new_rot;

        tf_new_rot.setRotation(qz90);

        transform_from_odometry.setRotation(qy90);

        transform_from_odometry.mult (transform_from_odometry, tf_new_rot);
    }

    broadcast();
}

void NodeImpl::broadcast()
{
     static tf::TransformBroadcaster br;
     br.sendTransform(tf::StampedTransform(transform_from_odometry, stamp, frame_id, "ego_vehicle_rear_axis"));
}
```

Comment: actually thats basic geometry. In a nutshell: Translate the object to the origin, rotate it around the origin, translate it back to its original position, done

Comment: The Tf::Transform I am using is already doing this. My problem is only about the rotation, I don't do any translation right now.

Comment: My first rotation is done around the world axes which is OK, but then the second rotation should be done around the axes rotated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which library you are using, so I'll try to give some generic advice on this.

Global vs Local rotations are just a matter of the matrix multiplication order. Let `R` be the final rotation matrix. When you multiply the X, Y and Z matrices using the following order `R=X*Y*Z`, then this would give you **Global rotations**, whereas `R=Z*Y*X` will give you **Local rotations**.

The problem with the above is that it limits your freedom for local rotations to the specific order Z-Y-X. For example, if you want to rotate, first *on* the x-axis, then *on* the y-axis, and then *on* the z-axis, the above would work fine. Anything else, is not going to give you the results you want. You would have to change the order of matrix multiplications.

If you want to rotate about an axis, let's say the *y-axis*, which is local to your object, then, you'd need to know where this axis is. You need to keep a reference of the current axes after each transformation and then, use the [Rotation matrix from axis and angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) to rotate about your current local *y-axis*.

```
/* from the wiki link above */    
Mat3 Axis_Matrix(float angle_, const Vec3 &axis_)
    {
        return Mat3{ cos(angle_)+pow(axis_.x,2)*(1.0-cos(angle_))              , (axis_.x*axis_.y*(1.0-cos(angle_)))-(axis_.z*sin(angle_)) , (axis_.x*axis_.z*(1.0-cos(angle_)))+(axis_.y*sin(angle_)),
                     (axis_.y*axis_.x*(1.0-cos(angle_)))+(axis_.z*sin(angle_)) , cos(angle_)+pow(axis_.y,2)*(1.0 - cos(angle_))            , (axis_.y*axis_.z*(1.0-cos(angle_)))-(axis_.x*sin(angle_)),
                     (axis_.z*axis_.x*(1.0-cos(angle_)))-(axis_.y*sin(angle_)) , (axis_.z*axis_.y*(1.0-cos(angle_)))+(axis_.x*sin(angle_)) , cos(angle_)+pow(axis_.z,2)*(1.0 - cos(angle_)) };
    }
```

You can basically create your own structure that does all this:

```
struct CoordinateSystem
{
    Vec3 current_x_axis;
    Vec3 current_y_axis;
    Vec3 current_z_axis;

    Mat3 local;

    void setRotationX(float angle_)
    {
        local *= Axis_Matrix(angle_, current_x_axis);
        update();
    }

    void setRotationY(float angle_)
    {
        local *= Axis_Matrix(angle_, current_y_axis);
        update();
    }

    void setRotationZ(float angle_)
    {
        local *= Axis_Matrix(angle_, current_z_axis);
        update();
    }

    void update()
    {
        current_x_axis = {-1.f, 0.f, 0.f} * local;
        current_y_axis = { 0.f, 1.f, 0.f} * local;
        current_z_axis = { 0.f, 0.f,-1.f} * local;
    }
};
```

Then you can just say:

```
setRotationX(45);
setRotationZ(10);
setRotationY(62);
setRotationX(34);
setRotationY(81);
```

And all the rotations would be local to your object.